# React Bug?? Container Improperly Growing When New Elements Added

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, next.js13

I am admittedly an absolute React newbie, but this seems like a bug to me.
Using `React 18.2.0` and `Next 13.4.8`...

**This bug impacts Safari but not Chrome.
A Reddit user proposed it may have something to do with AutoFill.**

The bug is in the background display of the Sign Up component, and it appears when you click into the password input, which triggers a checklist to appear and makes the background behave unexpectedly.

[Before click, working normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWbG6.png)

[After clicking on password input, background gets messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1CxA.png)

[After resizing the window or scrolling up or down the issue disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPI1k.png)

signup/page.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import SignupComponent from '../../components/Signup';

const SignupPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="py-16">
      <div className="max-w-md mx-auto my-10 p-8 bg-white shadow-lg rounded-md border-solid border-2 border-slate-100">
        <h1 className="text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900 mb-6">Sign Up</h1>
        <SignupComponent />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SignupPage;
```

components/Signup.tsx

```
'use client';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import { addFirestoreUser } from "../utils/addFirestoreUser";
import PasswordChecklist from "react-password-checklist"

const Signup = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [passwordClicked, setPasswordClicked] = useState(false);
  const [isPasswordValid, setIsPasswordValid] = useState(false);
  const [isEmailValid, setIsEmailValid] = useState(false);

  const handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && isFormValid) {
      handleSignup();
    }
  };

  const handlePasswordClick = () => {
    setPasswordClicked(true);
  };

  const validateEmail = (email: string) => {
    const re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
  };

  const handleEmailChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const email = e.target.value;
    setEmail(email);
    setIsEmailValid(validateEmail(email));
  };  

  const handleSignup = async () => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    try {
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      const user = userCredential.user;
      if (user.email) addFirestoreUser(user.uid, user.email, name);
      console.log('User created', user);
      // You can redirect or show a success message here
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Signup failed', error);
      // You can show an error message to the user here
    }
  };

  const isFormValid = isEmailValid && isPasswordValid;

  return (
    <div onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        placeholder="Full Name"
        className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm mb-3"
      />
      <input
        type="email"
        value={email}
        onChange={handleEmailChange}
        placeholder="Email"
        className="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm mb-3"
      />
      <input
        type="password"
        value={password}
        onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        onClick={handlePasswordClick}
        onFocus={handlePasswordClick}
        placeholder="Password"
        className={`appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-b-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm mb-4 transition-all duration-300 ${passwordClicked ? "mb-6" : "mb-4"}`}
      />
      <div className={`mb-4 ${!passwordClicked && "hidden"}`}>
        <PasswordChecklist
          rules={["minLength", "specialChar", "number", "capital", "lowercase"]}
          minLength={8}
          value={password}
          onChange={(isValid) => setIsPasswordValid(isValid)}
        />
      </div>
      <button
        onClick={handleSignup}
        disabled={!isFormValid}
        className={`group relative w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-blue-500 ${!isFormValid ? "opacity-50 cursor-not-allowed" : "opacity-100"} transition-all duration-300`}
      >
        Sign Up
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Signup;
```

Tried messing around with the Tailwind CSS properties to no avail...

Comment: Please include a [mre].

Comment: Looking at your screenshots, it seem more like browser's rendering artifact, it probably has nothing to do with your code or react. If you try it in other browsers you probably won't see it